# Indication de l'antécédent d'un pronom après le pronom et son verbe conjugué

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe

Je lis une traduction inhabituelle des Evangiles et j'ai remarqué des instances où l'antécédent d'un pronom est indiqué après le pronom et son verbe conjugué. Par exemple:

> - alors elle s'est levée **mariam** / dans ces jours-là
> - mais il est resté **ieschoua le garçon** / à ierouschalaïm

(Cette traduction n'a pas de ponctuation et de capitalisation.) Je me suis demandée, si cette construction est une tentative de conserver la structure de la langue du texte original, mais je me suis rappelée le titre de la chanson « Il est né, **le divin enfant** » où il y a la même construction.

Je rencontre rarement une telle construction. Apparaît-elle la plupart du temps dans certains types de textes? Est-elle vraiment rarement utilisée?

Comment: Que signifie "dans ces jours-là" dans la première traduction ? Cela n'a pas l'air d'être lié à la première partie de la phrase...

Comment: @Random: Je pense que "ces jours-là" réfère au temps de l'Annonciation. Voici la section dont j'ai cité ce fragment : "alors elle s'est levée mariam / dans ces jours-là / et elle s'en est allée dans la région montagneuse / en hâte / dans la province iehoudah"

Comment: Une traduction plus normale dit : "En ces jours-là Marie partit et s'en alla en hâte vers la montagne, en une ville de Juda." (Luc 1, 39)

Comment: La 2ème traduction semble beaucoup plus cohérente. Ce qui m'étonne dans la première, c'est l'ajout de "/" dans la phrase... Mais bref, ce n'est pas le sujet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela se fait à l'oral quand on se rend compte que l’antécédent n'est pas clair.

Cela se fait à l'écrit pour des raisons stylistiques, de rythme ou de rimes.  C'est beaucoup plus rare.

Dans le cas présent, l'hypothèse d'une traduction très littérale me semble une bonne piste.  Elle me fait penser aux versions interlinéaires, où le texte en langue originale et le texte traduit sont superposés en gardant autant que ce peut les correspondances, utilisées pour les analyses de texte.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Quand je considérais ce problème, j'ai remarqué que telle construction est indésirable en anglais, sauf aux circonstances assez similaires, mais je ne savais pas si le français a la même règle.

Answer (score 1):

A ma connaissance, cette construction n'apparaît pas plus souvent dans certains types de textes que dans d'autres. En particulier, je ne pense pas qu'elle apparaisse plus souvent dans la Bible ou les textes religieux que dans les autres.

Dans le passage que vous donnez, on dirait effectivement une tentative pour rester proche de l'original. On comprend le sens, mais ce n'est pas une formulation très "naturelle".

Je dirais que oui, cette construction est rare. Elle peut servir à mettre l'accent sur quelque chose ou à exprimer un sentiment (surprise, joie, désapprobation...), comme dans votre exemple "il est né, le divin enfant !". Autre exemple :

Le gredin s'est sauvé : neutre, on énonce un fait.

Il s'est sauvé, le gredin ! : colère, on insiste sur le fait que cette personne est un gredin, et il est sous-entendu qu'on aurait bien voulu qu'il soit arrêté.